# USA F4 category

Tags: usa

My sister have applied for my family sponsored case for USA in December,2006 (I was in India at that time). I am born in India. But after that I moved to United Kingdom and got citizenship here. 
So, My sister updated all the documents. On new letter from National Visa Centre, they have updated the case to London changing initial case number letters to LND from IND. But my country of chargibility is India. I understand, i have to look at F4 category on US visa bulletin  but under which country? Is it India or all other countries(because i am UK citizen now). 
Also, 1 of our cousin have similar case but their case was filed in December 2005. Their case status is 'Current' now. But India's case files are still on 2004. I am very confused. Can anybody help please?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your country of chargeability is your country of birth. Your citizenship or nationality is irrelevant. So you will still look under India as your country of chargeability.

If your spouse is immigrating together with you and your spouse has a better country of chargeability, then you can be chargeable to your spouse's country of chargeability if the two of you are immigrating at the same time.